# Getting NameNode's fsimage size using Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to get metadata about a NameNode from a running Hadoop cluster using Java.  Specifically, I would like to get the size of fsimage, the last checkpoint time, and number and size of the edit log files.

I'm aware that I can use the Offline Image Viewer to dump the contents of the fsimage file and I can also go to the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` directory to get the size of the fsimage files and the edit logs files.

However, I haven't found a way to get this information using the Hadoop Java API.  Is there a way to do this?

Any ideas?